# UIButton - Set property and use it when button is pressed

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I have a UIButton called Cell Button this is in my .h file

```
@interface CellButton : UIButton

@property (nonatomic,retain) CellButton *property;
```

In this cell I have 2 buttons both of the same class, and then I want to set `btn1.property = 0;` and `btn2.property = 1;` I set this in cell for row at indexPath.

Then I call this when the buttons are pressed:

```
[cell.Btn1 addTarget:self action:@selector(BtnClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
 [cell.Btn2 addTarget:self action:@selector(BtnClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Here is the method:

```
-(void)BtnClicked:(UIButton*)sender{
    DiningHallTableViewController *dtvc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"DiningHallTableViewController"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:dtvc animated:YES];

    //depending on what button is tapped I want to send the number of the button pressed
}
```

How can I make this sending the number?

**EDIT**

[image]

This is in my cellForRowAtIndexPath

In my method BtnClicked I have

```
 NSIndexPath *myIP = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:sender.tag inSection:0];

TwoMealsTableViewCell *cell = (TwoMealsTableViewCell*)[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:myIP];
```

Comment: What is the question? Your property should be typed to int not CellButton (@property (nonatomic) int property;). It's not clear that you need to subclass your button to do this. Are you setting the tag of the button to the indexPath.row?

Comment: @rdelmar yes the tag is already being used for that. I just want to add a property to the button in my cells. So I know if it was the first btn pressed or the second button pressed. Basically I want to know what button is pressed in the method that is called.

Comment: You can do that by checking the button's title if you want. Then you don't need to subclass the button.

Comment: You could also set a tag on each button. `button1.tag = 0; button2.tag = 1;` in cellForRow:atIndexPath:, then just get `sender.tag` in the callback method.

Comment: @rfj001 the title doesn't work because I don't know what title corresponds with what number, and I am already using tag to `indexPath.row`

Comment: I edited my answer below. See if that works.

Comment: It's really overkill to use a subclassed button for this task. You can use the button's tag to encode more than one item of information. For instance, you could give the firstMealButton a tag of indexPath.row and give the secondMealButton a tag of indexPath.row +10 (I assume this is for the same app that has 7 rows in the table). In the button method, tag/10 would give you 0 or 1, and tag % 10 will give you the remainder, which would be the indexPath.row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)table cellForRowAtIndexPath(IndexPath *):indexPath
{
      // Assuming one section, if not then just take section number into account when getting cell
      // You should be doing this part already
      cell = self.contentArray[indexPath.row];
      // Set tags on the buttons
      cell.btn1 = [[CellButton alloc] init];
      cell.btn2 = [[CellButton alloc] init];
      cell.btn1.property = 0;
      cell.btn2.property = 1;

      [cell.btn1 addTarget:self action:@selector(BtnClicked:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
      [cell.btn2 addTarget:self action:@selector(BtnClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

      // do anything else you need to do with the cells

      return cell
}

-(void)BtnClicked:(UIButton *)sender{
    DiningHallTableViewController *dtvc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"DiningHallTableViewController"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:dtvc animated:YES];

    //depending on what button is tapped I want to send the number of the button pressed
    if ([sender isKindOfClass[CellButton class]]) {
        property = ((CellButton *)sender).property;
    }

    // Now do whatever you need to do with the number
}
```

I also should add that you should do navigation via storyboard segues, assuming you're developing for iOS 5+, rather than creating a new VC and pushing it onto the stack. There are many tutorials online for using storyboard segues, [such as this one](http://www.appcoda.com/storyboards-ios-tutorial-pass-data-between-view-controller-with-segue/).

**THIRD EDIT**

From the screenshot, it's clear that your problem is in the code:

```
@interface CellButton : UIButton

@property (nonatomic,retain) CellButton *property;
```

You are setting the type of property as a CellButton, when you really want it to be an integer. Change the above line to

```
@interface CellButton : UIButton

@property (nonatomic) NSInteger property;
```

And the way that you are doing navigation just isn't in line with current best practices. Although if you're not using storyboards (I can't see why you wouldn't be) I suppose your solution works.

Comment: the tag property is already being used, and what wrong with pushing view controllers the way I am? I have added a screenshot to question

Comment: I don't have a contentArray what is should that be `cell = self.contentArray[indexPath.row];`

Comment: `self.contentArray` is just whichever structure you hold the content for your tableView in. I just picked a generic name

Comment: when I change it to I get and error saying `property with 'retain (or strong)' attribute must be of type object`

Comment: Take retain out of the parentheses when you are defining the property. NSInteger is not an object, so retain does not apply to it.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're getting that particular error is this line:

`@property (nonatomic,retain) CellButton *property;`

You're declaring `property` as type `CellButton` (inside the `CellButton` class, which is self-referencing & I'd be surprised if it worked).

When you set `property` in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` you're setting it to `0` or `1` which are of primitive type `int`, not of type `CellButton` - hence the errors.

To fix the error, do as rfj001 said & change your @property declaration.

`@property (nonatomic, retain) NSInteger property;`

Also, consider using ARC. Not necessary to mess w/retain counts & manual memory mgt anymore.